# Setting backbone model's property

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

After fetching a model, I want to set a certain property of the model that is based on the fetched attributes. How can I do this by using Backbone.Model.extend ?

Comment: What does the response to your fetch call look like? You can override parse in your model to put the retrieved attribute into the model's attributes. If you can provide an example response, I can show what that would look like.

Comment: I am fetching from my places so I want the code in one place. I don't want to repeat that code everywhere i do fetch. @kinakuta

Comment: The code would be in the parse you override on your model's definition.

Answer (score 2):

You could listen to the events on the model like this. The sync event is fired after the model has synced with your server so it should be after the fetched attributes.

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.on("sync", function(eventName) {
      /* your code */
    });
  }
});
```